# Independent android library with Google analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics, kotlin, android-library

**TL;DR**

> **Any chance to compile Google Analytics inside library module without any help from application module?**

I'm struggling for more than a week on how to compile an use GoogleAnalytics in my library.

The goals are:
 1. Compile and run GoogleAnalytics in android library
 2. Maintain an application context (Singletone? )

> **Here is how i'm trying to compile GoogleAnalytics in my library build.gradle file**

```
buildscript {

ext {
    support = '27.0.2' // https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html
    kotlin = '1.2.20' // https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html
    playServices = '11.8.0'
}

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
}
}
```

> **And the code that handles all analytics:**

```
class GenericSettingsAnalytics private constructor(context : Context) {

private val tracker = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(context).newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker)

companion object {

    private var instance : GenericSettingsAnalytics? = null

    fun getInstance(context: Context) : GenericSettingsAnalytics {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = GenericSettingsAnalytics(context)
            instance!!.sendInitAnalytics(context)
        }
        return instance!!
    }
}

fun sendEvent(category: String, action: String) {
    tracker.send(HitBuilders.EventBuilder().setCategory(category).setAction(action).build())
}

fun sendInitAnalytics(context: Context) {
    tracker.send(HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
            .setCategory(ANALYTICS_CATEGORIES.CATEGORY_APP_INFO.categoryName)
            .setAction(ANALYTICS_ACTIONS.ACTION_APP_INIT.actionName)
            .setLabel(context.packageName)
            .build())
}

}
```

Very simple one.
Everything works great in debug, but when uploading library to bintray (To use it's official compile) i'm getting the following exception:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.udioshi85.genericsettings, PID: 12398
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/analytics/GoogleAnalytics;
    at com.oshi.libgenericsettings.GenericSettingsAnalytics.<init>(GenericSettingsAnalytics.kt:14)
    at com.oshi.libgenericsettings.GenericSettingsAnalytics.<init>(GenericSettingsAnalytics.kt:12)
    at com.oshi.libgenericsettings.GenericSettingsAnalytics$Companion.getInstance(GenericSettingsAnalytics.kt:22)
    at com.oshi.libgenericsettings.GenericSettingsLib$Companion.initAnalytics(GenericSettingsLib.kt:20)
    at com.oshi.libgenericsettings.GenericSettingsLib$Companion.init(GenericSettingsLib.kt:16)
    at com.oshi.genericsettings.GenericSettingsApp.onCreate(GenericSettingsApp.kt:10)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5827)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1673)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:172)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6637)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics"
```

> **Some thougts:**

In my library build.gradle i'm adding the following classpath:

```
buildscript {
    ....
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    }
}
```

Is it correct?

Most common libraries counts on their users to init the library from an application class. Something like

```
class MyApp : Application() {

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    MyLibrary.init(this)
}
}
```

I've tried it already. but still getting the same exception. Maybe i'm doing something wrong?

> **Last thing, I've seen & read lots of examples on how to integrate GoogleAnalytics. The important thing is that my users should not add anything in their build.gradle except my compile/implementation library.**

Would appreciate if someone can help me with that.

Thanks very much!

Comment: Hi, Did you find a solution?

Comment: Hello Did you find the solution to this? Even I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

`buildscript` dependencies are the dependencies of your build script itself, not dependencies of your library. That is why it is not being included into your final build.

You can solve this issue by adding your `classpath` dependency to the application as well.

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    }
}
```